# How to generate dataset from videos for video classification in computer vision?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build data set for video classification. I am working on a specific project for which data set doesn't exist. My task is to classify video or scene in a video as some class. Can expert in computer vision share strategy to this task? What would be the steps? I feel like i will start with creating image data set from videos. Is it so? or please elaborate in detail.

Comment: This question is too broad to properly answer. Are you sure usable data doesn't already exist? Building a dataset tends to be a tedious and labour-intensive process, but it is hard to provide feedback without more information about the application and task you are working toward. There are crowd-sourcing platforms you may be able to utilize (eg. Amazon Turk) to help reduce the burden, but as your question stands it can't be neatly answered.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the question is about a fast and straightforward way of generating training sets. As was mentioned, it might be a nightmare to build a proper dataset by hand.

Solved similar problem by creating a specialized video processing tool. Here is an example of lips training set:

[image] 
([see details](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1xhBlYEPfo))

I'm experimenting with accurate segmentation, so the tool was required to avoid all the pain related to detailed object shape outlining.

The approach can be specified in several critical steps:

1. improve a video quality of the object/scene
2. improve object visibility (colour, contrast, etc)
3. find or develop a limited tool set, helping you to automate object extraction
4. collect video samples suitable for the tool set
5. use the tool set to crate a training set
6. use generate set to train a way more advanced model, which can be used as a common solution to your problem

For example, Les Twins movements can be used to collect  info about an ordinary shirt.

[image]
([see in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-vOm5rgMhI))

YouTube will also help if there will be a need to get grasshopper specific training set:

[image]
([see in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XnyOyaSNR6w))

Here are [more examples](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCLsVHuYpywKFNAHKFfImIVg/videos).